# chromium does not auto-detect hidpi

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

I'm trying to switch from the `google-chrome-stable` package to the `chromium-browser` package.

However the first thing I noticed is that chromium does not seem able to auto detect that I am on a hidpi device unlike google chrome. Launching chromium with `--force-device-scale-factor=2` works but this is not ideal.

Is there anything I can do to enable auto-detection of a hidpi screen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is a [known upstream issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515984) and it seems [fixed after the switch to gtk3](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=515984#c34).